# Adding bounty to an already bountied question

Tags: feature-request, bounty

There is a question with a +50 bounty and I realized I would like to add to that bounty to attract even more attention to it. As far as I understand that is not currently possible.

I think it is a worthy new feature which adds to one's ability to add attention to other people's questions (not too different than placing the first bounty on someone else's post)

ADDED

as per @gung comment, here is the question [Effect size and bootstrapping in paired t-test](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/183834/effect-size-and-bootstrapping-in-paired-t-test)

Comment: In the interim, you could attract more attention to the thread in question by listing it here in your Q.

Comment: See this answer on meta.SE [Is it possible to offer more points for a bounty that is already offered?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142600/is-it-possible-to-offer-more-points-for-a-bounty-that-is-already-offered/142602#142602) and also some relevance in this one [Is there any way to edit the bounty amount I allocated for a question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/268084/is-there-any-way-to-edit-the-bounty-amount-i-allocated-for-a-question/268085#268085)

Comment: I suspect the extra attention drawn to a question with a bounty on it varies little with the amount of the bounty, & that offering successive bounties will be more effective by keeping it in the 'Featured' list for longer.

Answer (score 7):

That seems reasonable, but it is beyond our control; it would have to be adopted by the developers.  You could ask on [meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) (but also note that they keep tabs on site metas to stay aware of requests like this).

Note however, that you can always add a bounty after the existing bounty has expired / been awarded.  The rules are that you may be required to add a bounty twice as large as the first ([source](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/bounty)).  This may have a greater effect of attracting more attention to the thread though, in that it would reside on the featured list for twice as long in addition to the higher bounty level.

Comment: +1 (edited) However, I think it only doubles if the previous bounty is yours (also note that the "at least twice as large" requirement ceases to apply once the maximum bounty - i.e. 500 - is reached .)